# where is google android api V2 cache located?

Tags: android, caching, google-maps-android-api-2

I've discoved that google map android api V2 save cache when we surfing. 
I want to know where it located on device to reuse.
Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the cache is located in the directory "Android/data/yourPackageApplication/cache" on your external sdcard.

If you find a way to manage this cache...